# AngularJS Date Format error with input control

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs, date

I have a view which lists a set of records that can be edited by clicking 'edit' at the end of the row. The records display correctly in 'display' mode but when converting to edit mode the date field is not populated. On rendering the page I get the below error in the console for each record.

> Error: [ngModel:datefmt] Expected `2014-12-28T00:00:00` to be a date

I have tried creating a directive to convert the date but this doesn't seem to work.

Directive:

```
    app.directive('jsonDate', function ($filter) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {

            //format text going to user (model to view)
            ngModel.$formatters.push(function (value) {
                var date = $filter('date')(value, ['yyyy-MM-dd']);
                return date;
            });

            //format text from the user (view to model)
            ngModel.$parsers.push(function (value) {
                var date = new Date(value, 'dd/MM/yyyy');
                return date;
            });
        }
    };
})
```

The view:

```
<td>
   <p data-ng-hide="competition.editMode">{{ competition.competitionDate | date: 'dd/MM/yyyy' }}</p>
   <input data-ng-show="competition.editMode" type="date" data-ng-model="competition.competitionDate" json-date />
</td>
```

If I output the value date to console it reports it as being an invalid date. How do I resolve this?

Comment: Are you using Firefox browser?

Comment: See in date:dd/MM/yyyy you are passing this format, but html-5 date expecting format as 2014-12-28 so try yyyy-MM-dd

Comment: This is in Chrome, I've changed all date formats to yyyy-MM-dd and still get the same. It seems that only ngModel.$formatters is being  called and not the second part ngModel.$parsers?

Comment: can you provide sample jsfiddle or plunker please?

Comment: try this http://plnkr.co/edit/aMDD4we3CEoLrQcoOq8t?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

What it means is that ngModel is expecting a javascript Date object.  In your row load code, transform the date (string) member of your object into a Date object.